# Select radio button by clicking surrounding table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I am constructing a Likert-scale in a HTML table. I need the following features:

1. Selected radio button can be unselected by clicking on it again
2. Selecting and unselecting the radio button must be doable by clicking on the table cell that the radio button is located in.

I was able to make 1. work but I am struggling with 2. I tried variations with `<label>` but without success or with undermining 1.

What is the cleanest way to do this? It seems that this should be a common design.

This is the current state:

```js
var allRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
var booRadio;
var x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++) {
  allRadios[x].onclick = function() {
    if (booRadio == this) {
      this.checked = false;
      booRadio = null;
    } else {
      booRadio = this;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}

.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 11px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 11px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-vt7q {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .tg-wo29 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.tg .tg-wo30 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .tg-wo31 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tg .tg-wo32 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tg .tg-wo33 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.item {
  height: 0px;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <col width="200px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-wo29"></th>
      <th class="tg-wo31" colspan="2">Gar nicht<br>hilfreich</th>
      <th class="tg-wo32" colspan="2">Sehr<br>hilfreich</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-wo29"></th>
      <th class="tg-wo33">0</th>
      <th class="tg-wo33">1</th>
      <th class="tg-wo33">2</th>
      <th class="tg-wo33">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-wo30">
        <div class="item" id="r1">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r1_0" name="r1" value="0" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r1_1" name="r1" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r1_2" name="r1" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r1_3" name="r1" value="3" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="tg-wo30">
        <div class="item" id="r2">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_0" name="r2" value="0" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_1" name="r2" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_2" name="r2" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_3" name="r2" value="3" />
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eL10qo6g/

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that like this

```js
var allRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

allRadios.forEach(radioBtn => {
  let isChecked = radioBtn.checked
  radioBtn.parentNode.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    isChecked = !isChecked
    radioBtn.checked = isChecked
  }) 
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}

.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 11px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 11px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-vt7q {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .tg-wo29 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.tg .tg-wo30 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .tg-wo31 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tg .tg-wo32 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tg .tg-wo33 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.item {
  height: 0px;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <col width="200px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-wo29"></th>
      <th class="tg-wo31" colspan="2">Gar nicht<br>hilfreich</th>
      <th class="tg-wo32" colspan="2">Sehr<br>hilfreich</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-wo29"></th>
      <th class="tg-wo33">0</th>
      <th class="tg-wo33">1</th>
      <th class="tg-wo33">2</th>
      <th class="tg-wo33">3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-wo30">
        <div class="item" id="r1">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r1_0" name="r1" value="0" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r1_1" name="r1" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r1_2" name="r1" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r1_3" name="r1" value="3" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="tg-wo30">
        <div class="item" id="r2">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_0" name="r2" value="0" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_1" name="r2" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_2" name="r2" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_3" name="r2" value="3" />
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems to require a double click to select a button

Comment: Thanks for the update! There still is a double click required to unselect the second value if two values have been selected.

Comment: @MaxJ. sorry, i have updated my solution again, its works perfectly now :)

Comment: One further thing I noticed, but it is really minor: When clicking on the cell instead of the button itself, the button does not light up and black out when being hovered/clicked. However, with the use of labels, the button would light up and black out even when only the label is clicked. Would that be possible in your solution?

Comment: I also noted that clicking on the cell now works, but clicking on the radio button itself does not

Comment: @MaxJ. Solution updated

Comment: Clicking on cells now works. But the buttons are not responsive when selected via clicking on the cell. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion giving labels is the best way to get clickable areas.
you can check fiddle i have attached with this.

I have added labels in the middle row just to prove the point.

[Click to view jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3x1ftao/)

```js
var allRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
var booRadio;
var x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++) {
  allRadios[x].onclick = function() {
    if (booRadio == this) {
      this.checked = false;
      booRadio = null;
    } else {
      booRadio = this;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
}

.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 11px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 11px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-vt7q {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .tg-wo29 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.tg .tg-wo30 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tg .tg-wo31 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tg .tg-wo32 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.item {
  height: 0px;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -9px;
    padding: 9px;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <col width="200px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <col width="50px">
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-wo29"></th>
      <th class="tg-wo31" colspan="2">Gar nicht<br>hilfreich</th>
      <th class="tg-wo32" colspan="2">Sehr<br>hilfreich</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-wo30">
        <div class="item" id="r1">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <label><input type="radio" id="r1_0" name="r1" value="0" /></label>
      </td>
            <td class="tg-wo29">
        <label><input type="radio" id="r1_1" name="r1" value="1" /></label>
      </td>
            <td class="tg-wo29">
        <label><input type="radio" id="r1_2" name="r1" value="2" /></label>
      </td>
            <td class="tg-wo29">
        <label><input type="radio" id="r1_3" name="r1" value="3" /></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
        <tr>
      <td class="tg-wo30">
        <div class="item" id="r2">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_0" name="r2" value="0" />
      </td>
            <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_1" name="r2" value="1" />
      </td>
            <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_2" name="r2" value="2" />
      </td>
            <td class="tg-wo29">
        <input type="radio" id="r2_3" name="r2" value="3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working great, thank you. Only thing I noticed (but that might have to do with the JS I used): When the same column is selected in both rows, a double click is needed to unselect the button.

Also: When I increase the height of a row (by changing the height attribute of item), the added space seems not to respond to clicks. Can this be achieved?

Comment: no i have not added labels in both rows. i just want to prove my point so that i just kept labels in one row.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was referring to another point